# Draw a graph inside map using Open layer and bing map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am new to work with Open layer version 7 api  , i want to draw a graph in map with js code  which the points are special locations and lines should join those locations
I used this examples , i link them below
I got confused how to do it , i think i should combine them but i couldn't

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-color.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/gpx.html

[i want something like this img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD8zp.png)

Comment: Do you want to draw your graph directly into the ol canvas?

Comment: yes exactly  i want to draw my graph directly into the ol canvas

Comment: You could use https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_ImageCanvas.html you need draw the graph by yourself or using something like this https://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: many Thanks for you answer, i think d3.js is better for my purpose but i don't know how to implement this graph inside my ol map, i want something similar to that img i uploaded

Comment: if you like to render svg you better check out this example here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/d3.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make Gpx file of location you want and then you will be fine
[use this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/gpx.html)

Comment: Can you explain a little more ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following code can read .shp files as zip and display them on the map.

```
import BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import View from 'ol/View';
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import vectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';

const place =[59.6067,36.2972];
const styles = [
 'RoadOnDemand',
 'Aerial',
 'AerialWithLabelsOnDemand',
 'CanvasDark',
 'OrdnanceSurvey',
];
const layers = [];
let i, ii;
for (i = 0, ii = styles.length; i < ii; ++i) {
 layers.push(
   new TileLayer({
     visible: false,
     preload: Infinity,
     source: new BingMaps({
       key: "API Key",
       imagerySet: styles[i],
       // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the BingMaps
       // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
       // maxZoom: 19
     }),
   })
 );
}
const map = new Map({
 layers: layers,
 target: 'map',
 view: new View({
   center: fromLonLat(place),
   zoom: 8,
 }),
});

const select = document.getElementById('layer-select');
function onChange() {
 const style = select.value;
 for (let i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {
   layers[i].setVisible(styles[i] === style);
 }
}
select.addEventListener('change', onChange);
onChange();
```

```
const featureStyle = new ol.style.Style({
 stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: 'red',
   width: 1
 })
});

map.getViewport().addEventListener('dragover', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
});

map.getViewport().addEventListener('drop',shpShow);

function shpShow(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 const files = event.dataTransfer.files;
 for (let i = 0, ii = files.length; i < ii; ++i) {
   const file = files.item(i);
   loadshp({url: file, encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(geojson) {
     const features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(
       geojson,
       { featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() }
     );
     const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
       features: features
     });
     map.addLayer(
       new ol.layer.Vector({
         source: vectorSource,
         style: featureStyle
       })
     );
     map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
   });
 }
}
```

```
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/lib/jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/lib/jszip-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.1/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/preprocess.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/preview.js"></script>
```